# Which file(s) are being sourced while opening a terminal on Mac?

Tags: terminal, zsh, macos, macintosh

So there are these files, which are being known for keeping environmental variables, aliases, custom shell functions etc.:

```
.bash_profile
.bashrc
.zshrc
```

and after installing `oh-my-zsh` (which I'm using) there's even more:

```
.zshrc.pre-oh-my-zsh
.oh-my-zsh/...
```

And maybe there are few others, which I don't know about.

Which ones are being sourced, when I open a terminal window? Does it depend on something? How can I check it?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on which shell (`bash`, `zsh`, etc.) your terminal starts up when you open it. For example:

- [Bash startup files](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html)
- [Zsh startup files](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Files.html#Startup_002fShutdown-Files)